# Python CSV writer keeps adding unnecessary quotes

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write to a CSV file with output that looks like this:

14897,40.50891,-81.03926,168.19999

but the CSV writer keeps writing the output with quotes at beginning and end

'14897,40.50891,-81.03926,168.19999'

When I print the line normally, the output is correct but I need to do line.split() or else the csv writer puts output as 1,4,8,9,7 etc...

But when I do line.split() the output is then

['14897,40.50891,-81.03926,168.19999']

Which is written as '14897,40.50891,-81.03926,168.19999'

How do I make the quotes go away? I already tried csv.QUOTE_NONE but doesn't work.

```
with open(results_csv, 'wb') as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(["time", "lat", "lon", "alt"])

            for f in file_directory):
                for line in open(f):
                    print line                        
                    line = line.split()
                    writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

with `line.split()`, you're not splitting according to commas but to blanks (spaces, linefeeds, tabs). Since there are none, you end up with only 1 item per row.

Since this item contains commas, `csv` module has to quote to make the difference with the actual separator (which is also comma). You would need `line.strip().split(",")` for it to work, but...

using `csv` to *read* your data would be a better idea to fix this:

replace that:

```
for line in open(some_file):
   print line                        
   line = line.split()
   writer.writerow(line)
```

by:

```
with open(some_file) as f:
  cr = csv.reader(f)  # default separator is comma already
  writer.writerows(cr)
```

Comment: I figured it out through trial and error, not even sure how it works but add these two lines worked line = line.strip()
                    line = line.split(",")

Comment: yes, but you'd be better off with csv to read the file as well as writing it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read the file manually. You can simply use csv reader.
Replace the inner for loop with:

```
# with ensures that the file handle is closed, after the execution of the code inside the block

with open(some_file) as file:
    row = csv.reader(file)  # read rows
    writer.writerows(row)   # write multiple rows at once
```